# Is it possible to generate an excel document using wso2 6.5.0 esb?

Tags: wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-esb

I have to do retrieve the data from database tables and then insert those data into excel file sheets. I am new to wso2 6.5.0, i want to do those task with esb. Is it possible to do with esb options? please guide me to do this use case.

Need to retrieve the multiple tables and inserts those data into multiple sheets.

Please someone could help me.

Answer (score 0):

As this question is not very specific: yes it is possible to generate an Excel file (CSV) using the datamapper mediator.
https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI640/Data+Mapper+Mediator